# Javascript table creating and populating from inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of inputs (a few radios, and a couple of checkboxes) as such:

```
<input type="radio" id="rd1" value="100" name="radios" class="slot" />
    <label for="rd1">Description of Radio 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="rd2" value="500" name="radios" class="slot" />
    <label for="rd1">Description of Radio 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="rd3" value="300" name="radios" class="slot" />
    <label for="rd1">Description of Radio 3</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="cb4" value="400" name="cb4" class="slot" />
    <label for="cb4">Description of CB 4</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb5" value="800" name="cb5" class="slot" />
    <label for="cb5">Description of CB 5</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb6" value="750" name="cb6" class="slot" />
    <label for="cb6">Description of CB 6</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb7" value="525" name="cb7" class="slot" />
    <label for="cb7">Description of CB 7</label>
```

I’m now trying to create a table with javascript that will update to show selected inputs in column 1, the values in column 2, then a total row at the bottom. (The table is generated with javascript as this is being re-used on 4 different tabs on the same page so by passing a new int to the function every thing gets a unique id so there aren’t conflicts).

The resulting format of the table should be:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
            <td>     <!— input ID (e.g. cb4) —> </td>
            <td>     <!—selected class cost —> </td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total: </td>
            <td id="costTotal"> <!— total of cost column —> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The js for creating the table is pretty much working and I’ll figure out the last bit but I’m struggling how to do the row insertion.

As checkboxes are selected their input ID and then the corresponding value should be inserted into the table with the total td then updating to sum it up. If you unselect a checkbox the corresponding row for that row is removed. Bonus points for having a new row added in ascending order (i.e. if radio 1 is selected, then cb3, and after that cb2, the row for cb2 appears between 1 and 3 when selected).

Any advice / suggestions / guidance on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, that i understand hole idea. Maybe so:

```
$(document).on('change', '.tbl-src input', function(){
  createTable('.tbl-src', '.table-holder'); 

});


function createTable(selectorSrc, selectorDest){
 var html = "<table>\
    <tbody>\
        <tr>\
            <th>Class</th>\
            <th>Cost</th>\
        </tr>";

  var sum = 0;  
  $(selectorSrc).find('input:checked').each(function(index, el){
     var $el = $(el);
    var val = parseFloat($el.val());
    var name = $el.attr('name');
     sum += val;

     html += "<tr>\
      <td>" + name + "</td> \
      <td>" + val + "</td> \
      </tr>";

  });

        html += "<tr>\
            <td>Total: </td>\
            <td id=\"costTotal\">" + sum + "</td>\
        </tr>\
    </tbody>\
</table>";
  $(selectorDest).html(html);
}
```

Try this code http://jsbin.com/cizovovo/2/

Comment: Works perfectly and very succinct code. Thank you very much! Could you offer one alteration - having the table creation and the update function separated so it's not dependant re-creating the table each time an input state is changed? Or is the performance impact of this so negligible it doesn't matter?

Comment: it depends on DOM size and count of Inputs. You can rebuild table by click on special button, But in case you have about 10-20 inputs - it not necessary. In common cause make optimisation and less DOM changes is better, but i think mostly it does not require worry